# C++ <algorithm> implementation explained

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

When I like to know how a algorithm in the C++ Standard Library could be implemented, I always look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm, which is a great source. But sometimes I don't understand some implementation details and I would need some explanation why something is done that particular way. For example in the implementation of [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n), why the first assignment is made outside the loop and the loop therefore starts with `1`?

```cpp
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_n(InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
    if (count > 0) {
        *result++ = *first;
        for (Size i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
            *result++ = *++first;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Additionally: Do you know a site where possible algorithm implementations are explained?

Comment: this possible implementation is based on the one [found in libc++](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/algorithm)

Comment: Also, general note: possible implementations on cppreference are only provided when a functionally correct, but generally far from optimal, implementation can be written in just a few lines of code: [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is pushing it, [std::stable_sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) is not gonna happen. Do look at real implementations in the C++ standard libraries such as LLVM libc++, GNU libstdc++, or what-have-you, if you're interested in what really happens (e.g. when `std::copy` is compiled as `std::memmove`)

Comment: @Cubbi: Before I asked this question, I looked at the MSVC implementation. I had to comb through a lot of function calls to reach the actuall implementation. Therefore I like the site cppreference for its "just a few lines of code" which are yet correct as the copy_n example showed. The algorithm implementations give an inspiration, how to write my one generalized, iterator based algorithms. I want to thank you for your valuable comments to this question and the given answers, I think it was you, how pointed out the bug with the naive implementation of copy_n.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Compare it with the naive implementation:

```
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_n(InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result)
{
  for (Size i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    *result++ = *first++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

This version does one more increment of `first`!

1. `count==0`, both do `0` increments of `first`.
2. `count==1`, their version does zero increments of `first`.  The above version does 1.
3. `count==2`, their version does one increments of `first`.  The above version does 2.

A possibility is to handle iterators that are dereferenceable, but not incrementable.  At least in STL days, there was a distinction.  I am not sure if input iterators have this property today.

[Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50119) is a bug that seems to occur if you use the naive implementation, and [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is some documentation that claims "The actual read operation is performed when the iterator is incremented, not when it is dereferenced."

I have not yet tracked down the chapter-and-verse for the existence of dereferenceable, non-incrementable input iterators.  Apparently the standard details how many times `copy_n` dereferences the input/output iterators, but does not detail how many times it increments the input iterator.

The naive implementation increments the input iterator one more time than the non-naive implementation.  If we have a single-pass input iterator that reads on `++` with insufficient space, `copy_n` could block needlessly on further input, trying to read data past the end of the input stream.

Comment: @RanEldan Who has an extra condition?  Where?

Comment: The OP's implementation has an extra if-test, which is more expensive than an extra increment.

Comment: @JimBuck Give an example input, and count the if-tests run, that shows an extra if-test?  I'm not seeing it.  Both do 1 more if-test than the number of items processed, exactly.

Comment: +1, but it may help to point out specifically that the naive implementation is wrong because copy_n has to support input iterators

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Which unnecessary objects are created?

Comment: `count == 0` -> the "naive" do 1 condition, the other does 2 condtion. 1 at the `if` and 1 at the `for`

Comment: @Cubbi: In what way does the shown naive not support input iterators?

Comment: @RanEldan Think about this again.

Comment: @RanEldan The non-naive does 1 if-test and returns with `count == 0`.

Comment: @MooingDuck http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50119 http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20110221/039404.html

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: Each call to postfix `operator++` requires the creation of a copy of the iterator in the current state before performing the increment.

Comment: @Cubbi Are there non-incrementable dereferencable input iterators?  I can find the citation in the old STL pre-`std` docs that imply that such can exist, but not in modern C++.

Comment: Hmm, "The actual read operation is performed when the iterator is incremented" from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator -- that looks like evidence.

Comment: @Yakk sorry, didnt notice the for is nasted inside the if

Comment: @MarkB the answer was here, all along.  :)

Answer (score 13):

That is just an implementation. The implementation in GCC 4.4 is different (and conceptually simpler):

```
template<typename InputIterator, typename _Size, typename _OutputIterator>
_OutputIterator
copy_n(_InputIterator __first, _Size __n,
     _OutputIterator __result)
{
  for (; __n > 0; --__n)
{
  *__result = *__first;
  ++__first;
  ++__result;
}
  return __result;
}
```

[With a bit of handwaving, since I only provided the implementation when the input iterator is an *input iterator*, there is a different implementation for the case where the iterator is a *random access iterator*] That implementation has a bug in that it increments the input iterator one time more than expected.

The implementation in GCC 4.8 is a bit more convoluted:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Size, typename _OutputIterator>
_OutputIterator
copy_n(_InputIterator __first, _Size __n,
     _OutputIterator __result)
{
  if (__n > 0)
{
  while (true)
    {
      *__result = *__first;
      ++__result;
      if (--__n > 0)
    ++__first;
      else
    break;
    }
}
  return __result;
}
```

Comment: As noted [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50119), the above implementation is incorrect. (What @Cubbi said, with more words)

Comment: @Yakk You should make an answer with that link, showing that a more naive implementation would be functionally wrong (due to the extra increment).

Comment: @Cubby: Correct, there is a bug in this implementation. Updated with the latest implementation in g++ 4.8

Comment: The MSVC 2012 library also has slightly different implementations for _input iterators_, _forward iterators_, and _pointers to scalars_ (calling `memmove()` in the last case).

Comment: Does the standard say *anything* about how the iterators may be incremented? I can't see it.

Comment: @KerrekSB the Standard does say "exactly n assignments", but nothing about number of iterator increments.

Answer (score 7):

With the naive implementation, you increment the input iterator `n` times, not just `n - 1` times. This is not just potentially inefficient (since iterators can have arbitrary and arbitrarily expensive user-defined types), but it may also be outright undesirable when the input iterator doesn't support a meaningful "past-the-end" state.

For a simple example, consider reading `n` elements from `std::cin`:

```
#include <iostream>    // for std:cin
#include <iterator>    // for std::istream_iterator


std::istream_iterator it(std::cin);
int dst[3];
```

With the naive solution, the program blocks on the final increment:

```
int * p = dst;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != 3; ++i) { *p++ = *it++; }   // blocks!
```

The standard library algorithm doesn't block:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::copy_n(it, 3, dst);    // fine
```

---

Note that the standard doesn't actually explicitly speak about iterator increments. It only says (25.3.1/5) that `copy_n(first, n, result)` has

> *Effects:*  For each non-negative integer `i < n`, performs `*(result + i) = *(first + i)`.

There is only a note in 24.2.3/3:

> [input-iterator] algorithms can be used with istreams as the source of the input
>   data through the `istream_iterator` class template.

Comment: Does increment cheeper than condition?

Comment: @RanEldan: Iterator increment can be a user-defined operation, so it can be as expensive as you like. And you're doing `n` comparisons either way!

Comment: General comment: My current understanding is that the standard makes no requirements on the state of a *stream* after it's been subjected on an algorithm that consumes an input iterator for that stream. I don't see anything that *forbids* the naive implementation. Cubbi's link above to the GCC bug is an interesting example of unexpected behaviour when "reusing" streams (and it is not clear to me that it is an actual bug, rather than a very insidious gotcha).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the initial check

```
if (count > 0)
```

we know that count > 0, therefore the author of that code felt that he didn't need to test against count again until he reached the value of 1. Remember that "for" executes the conditional test at the start of every iteration, not at the end.

```
Size count = 1;
for (Size i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

would print nothing.

Thus the code eliminates a conditional branch, and if Size is 1, it eliminates the need to increment/adjust "first" - hence it being a pre-increment.